# Editing my python code to see how many times I am recording the values of the parameters per second?

Tags: python, csv, raspberry-pi3

I am having a hard time with my python code. I already got it to run and create a csv file but I am having a hard time with implementing the lines that will tell the user how many times I am recording the values of the four parameters ( in my code) per second. The python code is attached below:

```
#Importing libraries
import csv

from ina219 import INA219
from ina219 import DeviceRangeError


SHUNT_OHMS = 0.1

read_ina = INA219(SHUNT_OHMS) 
read_ina.configure()

  
def read_all():
    
    data = {}
    data['Bus Voltage'] = read_ina.voltage()
    data['Bus Current'] = read_ina.current()
    data['Power'] = read_ina.power()
    data['Shunt Voltage'] = read_ina.shunt_voltage()
    return data

    
with open('SensorData.csv', 'w') as f:
    data = read_all()
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f,
                            fieldnames = list (data.keys()))
    writer.writeheader()


    exit = False

    while not exit:
        try:
            writer.writerow(data)
            data = read_all()
            
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            exit = True
```

This code calls the INA219 sensor and measures the Shunt voltage, bus voltage, power, and bus current of the Raspberry pi 3. I am trying to create a line within the code that controls how many times the parameters (Shunt voltage, bus voltage, power, and bus current) are being ran per second within the CSV file.

Comment: You want to write a running average or running measurement of the frequency of writes to every line? Or do you just want to add a timestamp to each line? And if you do need the frequency for some reason, do you want to base that off of the distance to the previous write and extrapolate, or do you want an actual count of the number of writes in the past second?

Comment: Hey Grismar, I am not sure exactly what you are asking. I am just trying to find a way to be able to tell how many times (in my ouput csv code that is created) the parameters are being ran per second. I hope this makes sense. For the overall four parameters, I am trying to control how many times the parameters are measured in a second ( in the csv file that is created if the code is ran). I hope this helps and gives you clarity

Comment: Couldn't you just time how long it takes to execute 'one write' and then divide 1 over this value? E.g. if it takes 0.1s to execute then you'll have 1/0.1=10 (10 times per second) - this of course would vary a bit from execution to execution

Comment: @koegl I am new to Python so what would that look like? Would I need to import the timer, sleep, or time package? I am not understanding exactly what it is that you are saying would you be able to clarify this?

Answer (score 0):

You can measure the execution time of any piece of code by saving the time before the start of the execution with `time.perf_counter()` and then subtracting it from the time after the execution is done (you need to add `import time` at the top of your code)

```
start_time = time.perf_counter()  # save the time before the execution

writer.writerow(data)

data = read_all()

compute_time = time.perf_counter() - start_time  # calculate the time it took to execute

data['Frequency'] = 1 / compute_time  # add the inverse to the data dictionary
```

You HAVE TO add this line of code to `read_all()` so that the Frequency column will exist from the first time you write anything to the file:
`data['Frequency'] = 0`

Comment: Hey I tried that, I get this error upon adding that:                                                   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/scripts/Assignment2 CreateCSV/SensorData.py", line 37, in <module>
    writer.writerow(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/csv.py", line 153, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/csv.py", line 149, in _dict_to_list
    + ", ".join([repr(x) for x in wrong_fields]))
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'Frequency'

Comment: I tried to add frequency to the data dictionary but am not sure what to link it to but am trying to look through and figure that out now

Comment: Have you added `data['Frequency'] = 0` to `read_all()`?

Comment: This way in the first iteration the frequency will be zero, but it will be correct in all the subsequent ones

Comment: Thank you @koegl, It worked. How can I determine how many times this is running per second? If asked to me, "how many times is it ran in a second", what would I say?

Comment: by doing this `1 / compute_time` you get what you're asking for. Example. It took 0.1s to, so you know it ran 1/0.1=10 times per second

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense! In my case it would be 10 x per sec. Thank you @koegl